# AssertionError: @api_view expected a list of strings, received str when passing slug

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I get this error when I try to pass slug in the url can anyone please assist or if there's any other way to implement this.

Below are the screenshots of urls.py | views.py | and models.py

I am using Django Rest Framework

[Urs.py Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9eSg.png)

[Views.py Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBqcL.png)

[Models.py Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKPtv.png)

[Error Which I am Getting!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdENx.png)

Please help!

Thanks in Advance.

incase the screenshot doesn't work below is the code of views

```
def blog(request):
    blog = Blog.objects.all()
    serializer = BlogSerializer(blog, many=True )
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view('GET')
def blogPost(request, slug):
    blogpost = Blog.objects.get(slug=slug)
    serializer = BlogSerializer(blogpost, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Below is the code of urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('blog', views.blog, name='blog'),
    path('blog/<str:slug>/', views.blogPost, name='blogpost')
]
```

Below is the code of models.py

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    sno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,  allow_unicode=True, blank=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    read_time = models.IntegerField()
    publish_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    hero_image = models.ImageField(blank=True,)
    content = models.TextField()
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)


    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.slug=slugify(self.title)
        super(Blog,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error says that @api_view requires a list of possible methods instead of a single string.

Change it to:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def blogPost(request, slug):
    blogpost = Blog.objects.get(slug=slug)
    serializer = BlogSerializer(blogpost, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the @api_view decorator expects a list of strings representing the allowed HTTP methods, but it's receiving a single string instead.

To resolve this issue, you should modify your blogPost function to pass a list containing the 'GET' string to the @api_view decorator. Here's the corrected code:

```py
@api_view(['GET']) # was previously @api_view('GET')
def blogPost(request, slug):
    blogpost = Blog.objects.get(slug=slug)
    serializer = BlogSerializer(blogpost, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```